# Error when running msfconsole in Pentestbox

Tags: ruby

In PENTESTBOX I want to run METASPLOIT-FRAMEWORK by running command msfconsole
and it is giving the following error ``

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ruby ":
>     In Gemfile:
>       ruby  x86-mingw32

```
metasploit-framework x86-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.83, which depends on
  ruby  (>= 2.5) x86-mingw32
```

Could not find gem 'ruby  (>= 2.5)', which is required by gem 'metasploit-framework', in any of the relevant sources:
  the local ruby installation

Comment: Try installing ruby 2.5 or greater

Comment: How can i do that

Answer (score 0):

To fix your issue run

```
gem install bundler -v 1.12

bundle _1.12_ install
```